WPF How to use a Button as ComboBoxItem
I'd like to include a few Button inside a ComboBox directly in XAML (not populated by a view model):
<ComboBox>
    <Button Command="{Binding PerformAction1}" Content="Action1" />
    <Button Command="{Binding PerformAction2}" Content="Action2" />
</ComboBox>

So, the ComboBoxItem correspond to a Button in order to directly execute a Command when clicked.
1st issue: When I click a button, the ComboBoxItem is not selected. I can change the  ItemTemplate in order to add a Button_Click callback.
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;

    var content = button.Content as Button; // Gets the the actual button within the button from the template.

    //content.Command.Execute(null); // content.Command is null.

    var cbi = UIHelpers.FindParent<ComboBoxItem>(button);

    cbi.IsSelected = true;
}

2nd issue: The Command binding is not executed from XAML and it seems that I can't get it from the code-behind.
Does someone have an idea how to solve it?

Why do ComboBoxItems need to be selected?

I tried to change the DataTemplate in order to include a Click event callback in order to select the ComboBoxItem as well (pure visual to show the Button content inside the ComboBox's TextBlock). Or is there a other way to select it?

Still unclear why ComboBoxItems should be selected at all. Anyway, the ItemTemplate does not make sense. It puts the "content" Button into another Button, so that there are two per item. That won't work. If you remove the ItemTemplate, Button Commands are executed as expected, so where exactly is the problem?

I would like to show which command was executed, more precisely display the button content (which is plain text) in the ComboBox's TextBlock. I'm still trying to adjust a few things but it seems that the ComboBoxItem does not get select when I click the Button. Perhaps I missed something somewhere else.

"Button as ComboBoxItem" is a terrible UX idea. ComboBox is a selector, handle selection change

The idea is indeed terrible. Why would you not take the typical approach of binding the SelectedItem or SelectedValue property to a view model property, and let the view model perform an appropriate action depending on the selection? Why does it need to be different ICommands?

Alright, I changed the ComboBoxItem by TextBlock and added an InputBinding <TextBlock.InputBindings><MouseBinding Command="{Binding Command}" MouseAction="LeftClick" /></TextBlock.InputBindings> which I've just discovered. I think it will be fine after some cleaning. Also, I want to keep the Command binding for compatibility instead of using a switch in the view model.

@ASh
I generally agree with you. But in practice I have encountered the need to perform actions when clicking again on an already selected element. In this case, using the SelectedItem binding will not help. You have to come up with some other ways of implementation: handling MouseLeftButtonDown/Up, Behavior and others. One of these ways is handling Click of an embedded button. And it does not look so bad compared to other methods.

I'll write right away that I agree with Clemens and ASh - the solution you've chosen is terrible. (See my reply to ASh' comment)
But for educational purposes I'll give an explanation and show a solution.
The button intercepts MouseLeftButtonDown/Up events, marks them as handled Handled= true, and raises the Click event. Since MouseLeftButtonDown/Up events have already been handled, the parent elements (including ComboBoxItem) "don't see" them.
Your use of the Click event is one of the solutions to this problem.
Using a nested button is definitely excessive.
It would also be more optimal to transfer most of the logic to XAML, but only do the most necessary in code.
An example of implementation:
    <ComboBox>
        <Button Command="{Binding PerformAction1}" Content="Action1"
                Click="OnSelectedItem"
                Tag="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Selector}}}"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding PerformAction2}" Content="Action2" 
                Click="OnSelectedItem"
                Tag="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Selector}}}"/>
    </ComboBox>
    <x:Code>
        <![CDATA[
            private void OnSelectedItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                Button btn = (Button)sender;
                btn.Tag = btn;
            }
        ]]>
    </x:Code>

You can also use interception of the bubble-event at the ComboBox level. This will simplify the XAML a little.
    <ComboBox ButtonBase.Click="OnBubbleСlick">
        <Button Command="{Binding PerformAction1}" Content="Action1"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding PerformAction2}" Content="Action2"/>
    </ComboBox>
    <x:Code>
        <![CDATA[
            private void OnBubbleСlick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                ((Selector)sender).SelectedItem = e.OriginalSource;
            }
        ]]>
    </x:Code>

